# Pass type to Json.encodeToString() without reified

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlinx.serialization

I'm having problem with `Json.encodeToString` . Because it's required `reified` type . But i can't provide reified type on my program. So, how i can get it happen for below code...

```
// I don't want to use reified
fun <I> encodeToString(model: I): String {
    return Json.encodeToString(model) // EROR: type mismatch
}
```

Please help to get rid of this problem. Any argument based solution or reflection would be good instead of `reified`

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `reified`?

Comment: I have an internal class which i can't instantiate because of the inline function.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i've converted the `KType` to `SerializationStrategy<T>`.

```
fun <I> encodeToString(type: KType, model: I): String {
    return Json.Default.encodeToString(Json.serializersModule.serializer(type), model)
}
```

And it works.

Comment: If you have access to the `KType`, then just doing `Json.encodeToString(serializer(type), model)` should work too.